# Statement not printing after colliding with an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a collision in my game, which is supposed to print Hello after colliding with an object. Instead, it does nothing but does not show any errors. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image: My game]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class kill : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        print("hello");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for what needed to trigger those events at here. You're probably missing some little details.

Comment: It turns out that both of my colliders were static colliders and two static colliders don't trigger the OnTriggerEnter2D function. I added a RigidBody2D with no gravity scale to the buss and it works now.